# Why is this a convex polygon?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, isometry

Let $\text{E}(2)$ be the group of isometries of the plane $\mathbb R^2$. Then $\text{E}(2)=\text{O}(2)\times\mathbb R^2$ as a topological space and is the semi-direct product as groups. Let $G$ be a discrete subgroup of $\text{E}(2)$ such that $\mathbb E^2/G$ is compact.  Let $p$ be any point of the plane which is not left fixed by any non-identity element of $G$.  Then
$$A=\{x\in\mathbb R^2\mid \|x-p\|\leq \|x-g(p)\|\text{ for all }g\in G\}$$
is a convex polygon.  I believe this but don't see how to prove it.  This must be a basic result somewhere but I can't seem to find it.  Thank you for any insight (or full answer).

If $x,y\in A$ to show convexity I have to show $tx+(1-t)y\in A$, $t\in[0,1]$.  So I need to show for $g\in G$ that
$$\|tx+(1-t)y-p\|\leq\|tx+(1-t)y-g(p)\|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any points $p$ and $q$,
$$ \{x\in\mathbb R^2 \mid \|x-p\|\le\|x-q\| \} $$
is a halfplane (or the whole plane if $p=q$), so your set is an intersection of halfplanes, hence convex.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I love this solution, it totally didn't occur to me to think about it in that way.